# KQL query to filter unique ID with highest value

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

If my KQL query is returning this

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1000 |
| 123 | 50 |
| 456 | 100 |
| 456 | 1400 |

How can I get it to return only one result per ID, of which has the highest value, e.g.

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1000 |
| 456 | 1400 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator)

```
datatable (ID:int, Value:int)
[
     123    ,1000
    ,123    ,50
    ,456    ,100
    ,456    ,1400
]    
| summarize max(Value) by ID
```

| ID | max_Value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1000 |
| 456 | 1400 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUBQ1PF6vMvBIdhbDEnNJUEFOTlyual0sBBAyNjDl1DA0MDCB8HTDfFMYzMTUDy6JwTUD8WJAAL1eNQnFpbm5iUWZVqkJuYoUG2ApNhaRKBU8XAODQymCCAAAA)